# Разница выражений "было и чем" и "было что"

Tags: общие-вопросы

Скажите пожалуйста, какая разница между "Пойти по этой дороге была моя вина" и "Пойти по этой дороге было моей виной".

Comment: Смысловой разницы нет. Или вас интересует грамматическая?

Answer (score 1):

Проблеме варьирования творительного и именительного падежа в сказуемых посвящена научная статья: [именное сказуемое при подлежащем "это"](https://www.gramota.net/articles/issn_1997-2911_2015_3-2_10.pdf) (для просмотра может понадобиться приложение, открывающие pdf-файлы).

Если коротко, то можно писать и так, и так, но не во всех предложениях получится корректно.